# Width doesn't update when screen rotates in html mail

Tags: html, css, email, mobile, html-email

So I have made a HTML email, with a mediaquery for screens under 399px width. Everything works fine until you open the mail on portrait mode(width under 399px), and then rotate your screen to landscape mode. When you rotate the screen it seems like the width doesn't update to the new width (let's say 450px, so the mediaquery isn't active).

When I have my phone in landscape mode, and then open the HTML mail everything is fine.

I've already tried different mediaqueries with `max-width`, `device-width`and `orientation: landscape`. In the head i've the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Here is my media query:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 399px) and (max-width: 399px) {
    #body_table {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: where's the code or media query? CSS rendering happens if you change the screen orientation. So, generally, you shouldn't get this issue. unless you are doing something wrong.

Comment: The CSS and media queries are in the head in a style tag, all the HTML is in the body tag, everything in just one html file.

Comment: share some code, so that we can see what's the issue

Comment: I've added my mediaquery, if you need some specif code let me know! Thanks for the help!

Comment: SO you have an ID and a class. Are those both on the `<td>` that you want to have go 100%?

Comment: also, add !important;

Comment: The styling isn't the problem because if you open the mail in landscape mode or portrait mode it's all good. The problem is that the media query or width doesn't update when you rotate your screen when the mail is open.